# Create NIO 2 FileSystem from current Jar

Tags: java, jar, nio

I'm trying to create `java.nio.file.FileSystem` from current Jar to extract something inside it. However, I couldn't get required Jar URI in any way. Which may be best way to do that?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is your answer ? :)

Comment: Please educate yourself on how to use StackOverflow http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I think question is clear, which part didn't you understand ?

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to copy some group of native files from current Jar to a known location. In that way, I first tried to create a FileSystem object from current Jar to use FileSystem's copy operation for easiness. However, it looks to me not easy and to make this happen, I got each resource as stream and copied them to current filesystem.

```
for (String nativeFile : nativeFiles) {
    InputStream inputStream = IOHelper.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + nativeFile);
    Path nativePath = dataDir.resolve(nativeFile);

    if (Files.notExists(nativePath)) {
        Files.createDirectories(nativePath.getParent());
        Files.copy(inputStream, nativePath);
    }
}
```